# Работа с веб-формой методом post

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь отправить запрос с необходимыми данными в обработчик формы методом POST.

```
data = { 'user': 'user', 'pass': 'pass'}
dataToReq = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
request = urllib.request.Request('http://example.ru/login.php?', dataToReq)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
```

Последняя строка выдает ошибку "TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be str". Но если преобразовать dataToReq в байты, то обработчик кажется не работает с этими данными. В примерах так же не требуется конвертировать в байты. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: А зачем знак вопроса в url?

Answer (score 2):

Плохо читали документацию: [20.5. urllib.request — Extensible library for opening URLs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/urllib.request.html)

> `data` may be *a bytes object* specifying additional data to send to the server, or None if no such data is needed.

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> req = urllib.request.Request(url='https://localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi',
...                       data=b'This data is passed to stdin of the CGI')
>>> f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
>>> print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
Got Data: "This data is passed to stdin of the CGI"
```

Comment: Всё чудесатее и чудесатее. Ставить 3.2 для проверки неохота, но по докам: приведённый отрывок из описания urlopen. А для класса urllib.urlrequest.Request чёрным по английски `data may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server, or None if no such data is needed.`

Comment: Если конвертировать в байты, то данные отправляются, но форма остается незаполненной и мне возвращается страница с этой формой. Что я здесь делаю неправильно?

Или эта страница может мне отправляется по какой то другой причине?

Comment: @alexlz, значит ошибка в документации, т.к. это одно и тоже по сути. Там используется банальная проверка на isinstance:

    def open(self, fullurl, data=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
        # accept a URL or a Request object
        if isinstance(fullurl, str):
            req = Request(fullurl, data)
        else:
            req = fullurl
            if data is not None:
                req.data = data

@Olegas, сделайте дамп запроса и посмотрите, что за запрос приходит.

Comment: @Olegas Ну сделайте, как питон просит. Не тираньте животину `request = urllib.request.Request('http://example.ru/login.php', dataToReq.encode())`. Ну а то, что example.ru юзера user с паролем pass пошлёт куда подальше, так это совсем другая история.